# How to access property via jq with special chars?

Tags: json, jq

Given this json file `wtf.json`:

```
{
  "I-am-test-v2": {
    "exist": true
  },
  "works": {
    "exist": true
  }
}
```

I can verify it has these keys via:

```
$ jq 'keys' wtf.json 
[
  "I-am-test-v2",
  "works"
]
```

I can access `works` via:

```
$ jq .works wtf.json
{
  "exist": true
}
```

yet I cannot select:

```
$ jq .I-am-test-v2 wtf.json
```

as that will yield in error:

```
jq: error: am/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.I-am-test-v2   
jq: error: test/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.I-am-test-v2      
jq: error: v2/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.I-am-test-v2           
jq: 3 compile errors
```

I assume it has to do with the special char `-`, yet I am unsure how to quote or escape it, as these attempts also fail with the same error:

```
 jq ".I-am-test-v2"  wtf.json 
 jq ."I-am-test-v2"  wtf.json
```

or some different error via:

```
jq ."I\-am\-test\-v2"  wtf.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.I\-am\-test\-v2  
jq: 1 compile error
```

I also tried:

```
jq .["I-am-test-v2"] wtf.json
```

How am I supposed to access the key?

Comment: Always quote your filters, preferably in single quotes when available. Otherwise the shell will interpret everything incorrectly and cause problems.

Answer (score 5):

Your key contains the dash `-` that is interpreted as the substraction operator.

You need to tell `jq` that it's a string by double quoting your key.

If you do that in command line, enclose your `jq` "script" into single quote in order to avoid your shell interpreting any special characters.

```
<wtf.json jq '."I-am-test-v2"'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it via proper enquotation via:

```
jq '.["I-am-test-v2"]' wtf.json 
{
  "exist": true
}
```

Then it also works with escaping:

```
jq ".[\"I-am-test-v2\"]" wtf.json
```

Note that you cannot reverse the quote style:

```
jq ".['I-am-test-v2']" wtf.json 
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.['I-am-test-v2']  
jq: 1 compile error
```